# how to add an spf record for both an external sender (like amazon SES) and self (via sendmail)

Tags: spf

We have a domain that sends mail both via sendmail and via Amazon SES.  The problem is, if we only add the SES domain:

```
"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"
```

Then sendmail won't let us deliver (this example is to gmail but it's the same problem for all):

```
050 >>> .
050 550-5.7.26 This message does not pass authentication checks (SPF and DKIM both
050 550-5.7.26 do not pass). SPF check for [domain] does not
050 550-5.7.26 pass with ip: [].To best protect our users from spam,
050 550-5.7.26 the message has been blocked. Please visit
```

But if we add our domain:

```
"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com include:ourdomain ~all"
```

Then we get a recursive error:

```
Error : We have detected recursion for the domain
```

So how do you create an spf record for the domain that includes the domain AND that allows an external sender?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the below txt record:

```
v=spf1 ip4:54.240.0.0/18 ip4:<server_public_ip> ip4:<server_private_ip> ip4:<my_fixed_ip_1> ip4:<my_fixed_ip_1> include:amazonses.com include:smtp-out.amazonses.com include:_spf.google.com -all
```

My understanding, is that a TXT record for SPF was requested, letting the world know you approve both of your own Server sending emails, and a second mail service as AWS SES, as legitimate senders via their IPs.

So:

v=spf1 is the opening;

here can come a list of IPs (CIDE range allowed) of AWS SES  and your server and you which each record starting with ip4:....,

then comes "+a" " which is the "a" record IP of your server on the DNS table,

then you add the mx records via "+mx",

then +a:your_domain.com" which may be suitable for mail.example.com SPF to point to the main domain's "a" reocrd,

then you include the AWS name by "include:amazonses.com",

I have also included the MX value used on the emails: "include:smtp-out.amazonses.com"

apparently you need to include google for gmail to accept emails (possibly due to autowoard): "include:_spf.google.com", and at the end you prevent ANY other IP from being approved by adding "-all".

Note: 54.240.0.0/18 is the IP CIDR range AWS uses to send my emails.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to list the IP address(es) of your own server(s) with the `ip4` or `ip6` SPF mechanism instead of including your own domain. Example: `v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ip4:127.0.0.1 ~all`. If you want, you can list your own IP addresses on a subdomain and then include this subdomain in your SPF record.